# Webpack copy files from dist to another directory

Tags: webpack

Hope I'm saying this correctly. I have a Vue2 project that I need to create multiple bundle.js/css and copy to different directories. I would need all the files from the dist folder and copy to another.

I've been searching online but confused with all the different approaches which is not working for me. Below are a few approaches I tried.

Approach 1 = webpack.prod.conf.js

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ]),
```

Approach 2 = webpack.prod.conf.js

```
entry: {
  app: './src/app.js',
},
output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    //filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    //chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].js')
  },
```

Approach 3 = index.js

```
  build: {
    // Template for index.html
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),

    // Paths
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',

    /**
     * Source Maps
     */

    productionSourceMap: true,
    // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#production
    devtool: '#source-map',

    // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
    // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
    // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
    // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],

    // Run the build command with an extra argument to
    // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
    // `npm run build --report`
    // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  }
}
```

Comment: So, let's start with approach 1 then. Any errors? Have you tried to simply output the paths to see that they are what you expect (i.e `console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'));`? Have you installed copy-webpack-plugin? (Isn't the ignore a glob? so `ignore: ['.*']` might just ignore every file you are trying to copy?)

Comment: Yes, I have copy-webpack-plugin installed. All the approaches work because I installed Vue cli which comes with webpack. I need to alter the code so I can make a copy of the static folder that has the complied assets, bundle.js, and bundle.css to another directory

Comment: Aha. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-plugin Here.  You want to tap `config.plugin('copy')`

Comment: How would I use config.plugin('copy')

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-plugin

It may look something like this (this is not tested (sorry I'm lazy!), but I've used similar code many times and I guarantee you can modify the config this way, but better have a look at those `args` to be sure. )

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .plugin('copy')
      .tap(args => {
        console.log(args);
        args[0].from = "something"; //modify 
        args.push({from:"...", to:".."}); //add
        return args;             
      })
  }
}
```

You can peek at the current config using `vue inspect > somefile.js`. It's super useful with webchainpack because it has comments with what stuff you can tap into.

Comment: I'm new to webpack I need to look into chainWebpack.

Comment: Does this work for Vue CLI 2? I see it's for Vue CLI 3

Comment: Ah, sorry. no. I *think* this is vue cli 3+ only.